# How access to web socket request attributes in Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, jetty, x509

I want to use client authentication with x509 certificates for web sockets.
I configured everything in the jetty and it works fine.

I want to extract Distinguished Named from a client certificated.
There is no problem with doing that in a plain HTTP servlet via request attributes, but web socket Session object doesn't provide them.

I found here a private field of the upgrade request ((JsrSession) session).getUpgradeRequest().request, which has request attributes with certificated.

Is there any other more clean way to extract this information?

Can I use a servlet filter to put attributes into header?